# How to prove a function is periodic?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }2n-1<x<2n,\\0&\text{if }2n<x<2n+1. \end{cases} $$
Is this function is periodic or not? How can I prove it?

Comment: I assume one should add "for some $n\in\mathbb Z$" somewhere.

Comment: How is $f$ defined at the integers?

Comment: Try to draw the function. Then you can read Hagen von Eitzen's answer.

Comment: It looks like $f$ is $1$ between an odd an an even, and $0$ between an even and an odd. Evens and odds repeat every two numbers, so I'd expect this to have a period of two. (Try imagining a graph of this!)

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined on $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z$ and has period $2$.
To show the latter note that if $2n-1<x<2n$ then $2n'-1<x-2<2n'$ with $n'=n-1$ and if $2n<x<2n+1$ then $2n'<x-2<2n'+1$ with $n'=n-1$.

Comment: how did you got period is 2 at first?